# Active links not working on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am really new with bootstrap, and I'm trying to apply the active class to a menu, but for some reason is not working, I don't know if it is the jquery function (I got it from a tutorial) or if bootstrap won't allow the use of active links.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/021qbcvd/)**

HTML

```
  <div class="masthead">
  <nav id="topNav" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified"> 

      <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../cars.html">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="../model.html">Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="../colors.html">Colors</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </nav> <!-- /Top Navigation -->
  </div> <!-- /masthead -->
```

CSS

```
nav-justified a.activee {
    background:red !important;
    }
```

JS

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.nav-justified a').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href')  ===  window.location.pathname) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('activee');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? It says `activee` and should say `active`.

Comment: @Dan But if both names match is not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript code you're checking to make sure that the `href` attribute of your link is equal to `window.location.pathname` but, in your JSFiddle, none of the links have a matching attribute. Try this instead:

```
  <div class="masthead">
  <nav id="topNav" role="navigation" aria-label="Top Navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified"> 

        <li><a href="/021qbcvd/7/show/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../cars.html">Cars</a></li>
      <li><a href="../model.html">Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="../colors.html">Colors</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </nav> <!-- /Top Navigation -->
  </div> <!-- /masthead -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/021qbcvd/7/

Note that `window.location.pathname` is equal to everything after the main URL. I had to do an `alert(window.location.pathname)` to get the correct one for the JSFiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by a alert(window.location.pathname)

Comment: I just meant that, since I didn't know what the value of window.location.pathname would be for the JSFiddle, I had to use `alert(window.location.pathname)` in order to figure it out. That command will just pop up an alert box that tells you the value of the variable.

Comment: ooh i seee, this mean that I need to include the forder name before the html name ?

Comment: You'll need to include everything after the .com (or .co or .org or whatever). For example, `window.location.pathname` for `foo.org/hurp/durp.html` will be `"/hurp/durp.html"`.

Comment: now I understand thank you ! just a final question, theres no way to just read the html name ?

Comment: Sure there is: http://befused.com/javascript/get-filename-url. You'll have to do that to both the `window.location.pathname` variable and do your `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks you, i'm going to try that

Answer (score 1):

if you use twitter-bootstrap 3,can use this code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">



<div class="container-fluid">


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CARS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MODEL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">COLORS</a></li>                 

            </ul>           

    </div>


</div>
```

and use `class="active"` in li tag to show active page

Comment: I think that Im using a different version of boostratp, because nothing happen when i had it the active class

Comment: open bootstrap.css and in top writed version of bootstrp like : * Bootstrap v3.1.1 or Bootstrap v2.3.1